# How to appear cursor on textarea with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, textarea

I'm writing a script that will tab through various form elements (radio, checkbox, etc.), and the one element that's proving to be a bit tricky is `<textarea>`.

To be clear, I want to mimic the behavior of clicking on a `<textarea>` that brings focus and a cursor for user keyboard input from an external JavaScript file, specifically an Angular controller.

***What I've tried***

I've tried:

- [focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus)
- [click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

Comment: [I don't see why `.focus` and `.click` won't work.](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/ycn6jksb/) Can you add a demo to your question?

Comment: Yes, I see that these work typically, but they do not work in my case. Perhaps I should try to understand my problem a bit more and get back to you.

Comment: maybe the text area wasn't loaded in the dom, focus will only work if the element is there.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var area=document.getElementById('textarea');
area.value="hello from javascript";
```

```html
did you try the autofocus attribute ?

  <textarea autofocus  type="textarea" id="textarea" rows="6" cols="70"></textarea>
```

Comment: Autofocus certainly works when hardcoded into html, but I would like to set the focus conditionally.

Comment: @PeterWard You could easily do that with some php, have you considered that an option?

Comment: I'll be back indoors in about 30 and I'll look then, when you tried focus() did you use an ID or get the element through the dom

Answer (score 0):

```js
  
    var area=document.getElementById('textarea');
    area.focus();
    var counter=0;
    var string="Hi from focused area ";
    var strlength=string.length;
    
    window.setInterval(typeWord,300
     
);    

function typeWord(){

              area.value+=string[counter];
  counter++;
  if(counter==strlength){area.value+=" ";counter=0;}
   

};
```

```html
      <textarea   type="textarea" id="textarea" rows="6" cols="70"></textarea>
```